# Extracting and comparing Int in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to compare the integers in an array to another int in this way:

```
if (i == the integers in the array) {

        }else {

        [image1 addSubview:textname];

            }
```

and...

```
indexDelete = text.tag;

[myIntegers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexDelete - 1]];

NSLog (@"Array: %@", myIntegers);
```

The console shows:

```
Array: (
0,
1,
2
)
```

And i is an integer in a for loop that keeps increasing by 1

Any ideas on how I can do this??

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have to either loop through the array OR use this somehow https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work using indexOfObject:

```
for (int i ...) {
    NSNumber *numberI = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];

    // Check if i is not equal to one of the numbers in the array
    if ([myIntegers indexOfObject:numberI] == NSNotFound) {
        // Run set of functions
    }
}
```

Or a simple for loop:

```
for (int i ...) {
    BOOL found = NO;

    for (NSNumber *number in myIntegers) {
        if ([number intValue] == i) {
            found = YES;
        }
    }

    if (found == NO) {
        // Run set of functions
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say but none of the first two work,don't know why, the third is irrelevant to my problem...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question then. You do have a for loop with an "int i" which keeps increasing, and want to do something specific if that "i" can be found in the array "myIntegers" ? Could you provide a little more code if I am wrong ?

Comment: Ok, so I have a set of functions in a for loop with the int i which increases. I want to run the setvof functions only if i at that point in the loop is not equal to one of the numbers in the array...

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope this time it can solve your problem.